# How to make a connection string on SQL database

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, web-config

Hello I have a database used in Microsoft SQL Server management as\
DesktopHat/SQLEXPRESS/Databases/webhooks

Whenever the line of saving the database executes I get an error

Is is something with my connection string?

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=DesktopHat\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-webhooks-20151117232236;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    <add name="DBContextEntity" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBContext.csdl|res://*/DBContext.ssdl|res://*/DBContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connectionstring=data source=DesktopHat\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=webhooks;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

I am currently using .NET and SQL

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Sometimes the easiest thing is to use LINQPad to set up a connection, and then copy the connection string from there. It's pretty self-explanatory / obvious how to do it. Just download LINQPad and "play around with it" and you'll probably figure it out.

Comment: All it says is that there no .dll source file or something.

Answer (score 0):

The error may be with Database name:

> Initial Catalog=aspnet-webhooks-20151117232236

The Initial Catalog should be the name of Database you want to use.

Or

may be with SQL Database accessibility, 
The given Connection string will work if you have Windows Authentication and the same will work if your SQL server do supports Windows Authentication

Or

may be with Connection String you are providing when the line of saving database ececutes.

> name="DefaultConnection" or name="DBContextEntity"